# Item overlap on its container

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, vb.net

i got trouble with my gridview, which overlap on its container,

[image]

and here's my code for datagridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="PayId" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Black" PageSize="20"
                            Width="100%" BorderColor="Black" CssClass="zebra"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" >
```

and when i generate the row , on datagridvie bound, i use :

```
Protected Sub gvData_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvData.RowDataBound
        For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
            e.Row.Cells(i).Attributes.Add("style", "white-space:nowrap;")
        Next
End Sub
```

for the container i already set em on master page, with css class :

for the wholoe page :

```
#PublicWrapper.width100 {
    width: 92%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    float:left;
    left: 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: -48%;
}
```

for the body :

```
body.modern{
    background-image: url(../Images/);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: #353f5b;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

and for the grid container :

```
body #PublicWrapper .placeholder_5.sf_cols {
    background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

i already add     `display: inline-block;` but the container and the body didn't display on center screen, but my problem is resolved. is there any tricks on css should i use to make the body fit on center screen but the grid didint overlap?

Comment: Can you show more code for container ?

Comment: How should you do when your row overflow?  
use `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;`   
Your grid need to fix column size.

Comment: i already update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use percentage in your width ,use pixel size

can you change the `Width="100%"` to `Width="1000px"`

Comment: it still overlap, is it `white-space:nowrap;` fault?